# With MySQL, how can I calculate a view field basing on a semi-related record?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm sorry for the vague title, but what I want to do can hardly be described with a one-liner.

I have a simple web app with a MySQL 5.1.30 backend to help me manage my finances. It's got a `bill` table:

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
date DATE
```

And a `bill_rows` table:

```
id INT,
bill INT REFERENCES bills (ID),
cost DECIMAL(16,2),
taxable TINYINT(1)
```

And finally, a `taxed_bill_rows` view, where an additional `taxes` column is introduced:

```
SELECT
    r.id AS `id`,
    r.bill AS `bill`,
    r.cost AS `cost`,
    (CASE
        WHEN i.taxable
            THEN floor((r.cost * 1.05 * 1.075) * 100) / 100.00 - r.cost)
        ELSE
            0.00
    END) AS `taxes`
FROM bill_rows r
```

The 1.05 factor is the federal tax rate, and the 1.075 is the provincial tax rate. (The `* 1.05 * 1.075` is not a mistake: the provincial tax is applied over the federal tax too.)

However, these values aren't up-to-date anymore (I'm actually very late on this). Since January 1<sup>st</sup> of this year, the federal tax rate is 1% higher, up to `1.085`.

To solve the tax rate changes problem, I've created a new `tax_rates` table:

```
ID INT,
date DATE,
federal DECIMAL(4,2),
provincial DECIMAL(4,2)
```

Each time the tax rates change, I will insert a new record there.

Now, the problem is, how can I access the relevant tax rates, based on the `date` field of a bill, from my view? I can't just do `LEFT JOIN tax_rates tr ON tr.date < b.date` as that can potentially bring back too many records. Adding a `tax_rates` foreign key to the `bills` table would do it, but the changes are so occasional that it seems barely worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tax_rates` table needs two date columns to indicate the start & end:

```
CREATE TABLE tax_rates (
  id INT,
  start_date DATE,
  end_date DATE,
  federal_tax_rate DECIMAL(4,2),
  provincial_tax_rate DECIMAL(4,2))
```

Then, you can use BETWEEN to JOIN:

```
JOIN tax_rates tr ON tr.date BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date
```

Comment: I suppose the current tax rate needs to have an "infinitely far" end date?

Answer (score 0):

foregn key for tax rate will be the best solution.

best for performance and best for maintenance,

any other solution will be slower and less readable

i.e you can add fields start_date and end_date to tax_rates table
and to do join like

```
left join tax_rates tr on b.`date` between tr.start_date and tr.end_date
```

in this case you also should keep 0 at start_date for first record and large date for last record

Comment: You don't use foreign keys for performance -- they're for data integrity.  Storing the computed value would be quicker than joining to another table too.

Comment: in your case you still make join. And join by foreign key much faster(and valid, and readable) then join by calculations

Comment: Performing the calculation once, and storing the result for retrieval will always be faster than joining.

Comment: and? your example is still join. Provide example with stored callucations and this will be subject to discuss.

Comment: It's your claim, you prove it